# y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape {} instead. What should I do?

Tags: python, deep-learning

```
%matplotlib inline
from google.colab import files
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from xgboost import plot_importance



train = pd.read_csv("train.csv", index_col=0)
test = pd.read_csv("test.csv", index_col=0)
submission = pd.read_csv("sample_submission.csv")

X = train.iloc[:,:9]
Y = train.iloc[:,9:]
X


seed = 5
test_size = 0.33
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=test_size, random_state=seed)


model = xgb.XGBClassifier()
model.fit( X_train, y_train)
```

test.csv
[test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9VaF.png)

train.csv
[train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwkUs.png)

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
2
3 model = xgb.XGBClassifier()
----> 4 model.fit( X_train, y_train)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in column_or_1d(y, warn)
1023
1024     raise ValueError(
-> 1025         "y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape {} instead.".format(shape)
1026     )
1027

ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (3210, 0) instead.

Help me Please..
What should I do..?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text or data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. And if you have tabular data, please format it as a table of text.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your error comes from the type of data that you use for the y value : it is a dataframe because you use this syntax `Y = train.iloc[:,9:]`. You should try with a Pandas Series : `Y = train.iloc[:,9]` (remove the colon at the end)